# What are the benefits of only_full_group_by mode?

Tags: mysql, sql

I updated mysql and I went from MySQL Version 5.6.17 to version 5.7.14

Since I have errors on my sql queries

Indeed, many of my queries look like this:

```
SELECT count (id) as nbr, lic from prep WHERE key = '18'
```

And I have this error:

> 1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'operator.preparation.orig_lic';
>   this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

After some research, I learn that Mysql 5.7.14 activates ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY by default

Why is it enabled by default?

What is the best solution (for performance)? Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY or add a 'group by' on my query?

Thank you

Comment: only_full_group_by forces you to name all SELECT fields within the GROUP BY cause.. this way you can't write wrong GROUP BY querys that not name all fields... read this https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: @RaymondNijland Great post on GROUP BY mode 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'. I was searching for such a presentation. Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 43):

**only_full_group_by = on** tells MySQL engine: Do not apply `GROUP BY` when you have doubt about what results to show and throw an error. **Only** apply it if `Group By` specifically tells you what to do. i.e. when the `Group By` is full and perfect!

**only_full_group_by = off** tells MySQL engine: always apply `GROUP BY` and if you have doubt about what results to choose, just pick one randomly!

**You don't have to turn it off if you use  `GROUP BY` properly!**

**Example:**

Table: users

```
 id   |  name
----------------
  1      ali
  2      john
  3      ali
```

When you use `GROUP BY` on the `name` column:

```
SELECT * FROM users GROUP BY name;
```

There are two possible results:

```
  1      ali
  2      john
```

OR

```
  2      john
  3      ali
```

MYSQL does not know what result to choose! Because there are different `id`s but both have `name=ali`.

**Solution1:**

only selecting the `name` field:

```
SELECT name FROM users GROUP BY name;
```

result:

```
  ali
  john
```

This is a perfect solution. removing columns that makes `GROUP BY` confused. This means you know what you're doing. Usually, you do not need
those columns, but if you need them, go to **Solution3**!

**Solution2:**

Turning off `only_full_group_by`. MYSQL will pick one of the two possible results **RANDOMLY**!! (It's ok if you do not really care what `id` it will choose, but remember to **turn it on** immediately after your query to prevent unexpected behaviors in future groupBys)

**Solution3**

Use an `Aggregate` function like `MIN()`, `MAX()` to help MYSQL to decide what it must choose.

For example:

```
SELECT MAX(id), name FROM users GROUP BY name;
```

result:

```
  2      john     
  3      ali
```

It will choose the `ali` row which has the maximum `id`.

Comment: **Thank you** for this brilliant explanation of what for years has seemed to me a bizarre, unhelpful, painful and arbitrary rule serving only to irritate developers. 

Answer (score 12):

The "best" solution is to do the correct thing and fix your query by adding a `group by`, rather than override the error being thrown. If you override the error with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` the error you're experiencing will go away but you'll likely experience two new errors as a result of doing so:

1. Unexpected results of including an aggregated value with non-aggregated values, the problem your error is trying to prevent.
2. Inability to execute your query on other environments. If you ever need to switch settings or give your code to someone else not using this database, the query will throw the error again. If you get into a habit of overriding the error or other errors, your code could become unusable to others and severely cripple the usefulness of it.

In general, if you are receiving an error, fix it rather than just telling the compiler/optimizer to ignore it.

Comment: adding group by not always return what we want. For example, `SELECT sum(amount) as totalAmount, IF(action="+", amount, 0) as totalInGoing FROM `transactions` where account_id = 32099` this query, with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode, requires `GROUP BY action` to work. which makes totalInGoing useless because it will return severel rows.

Comment: Most people aren't trying to switch off something useful. I ended up here because I wanted to find out why what appeared to be a totally arbitrary and useless block (i.e. ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY) was there in the first place. @ahmad-maboraki's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65680378/1490889) explains admirably what's going on, why ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is there, how to work with it rather than around it, and why that helps.

Answer (score 7):

The correct solution is to add the column you group by:

```
SELECT count (id) as nbr, lic 
from prep 
WHERE key = '18'
group by lic
```

for the performance this depends on the index you have.

The `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`  is the normal behavior for aggregation function in SQL and the adoption is 5.7 to avoid ambiguity on the casual result for non aggregated column result.

Comment: Thank you but it changes something to do the group by on the id or on the lic ?

Comment: change  completly .. the column you set in group by are usea as key for aggregation .. so eg: if you want  th count of rows with the same lic youuse group by lic .. otherwise if you want the number of row for another column you don'u tse lic  but the other column name  .. if you case you are counting the number of not null id group by lic

Comment: Thank you but on query like this : **SELECT user_name, validated.user, via, master, nb_jours, min(date) as date_min from validated, users_instruction where is_finish = 0 and user = cust_id and users_instruction.br = validated.br group by master order by date_min ASC** I can't use Group by ?

Comment: Using group by you should have, in group by, all the columns not in aggregation function ( user_name  , validated.user  , via  , master  , nb_jours)

not only  master ..  but this seems a new request  .. try add a new question with a proper data sample and the expected  result