# 500 error when using mysql date function and count function together

Tags: mysql, group-by

Tried:

```
SELECT DATE(`time`), HOUR(`time`), COUNT(*) 
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY DAY(`create_time`), HOUR(`create_time`)
```

This is work on mysql but fail on php, wonder know why and how to solve it

Thanks!

Comment: I use php 7 and mysql 5

Comment: Please tell us what the error is. Also provide your real code. Your `group by` should have columns in your `select` query.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the column in select and group by are the same,
i just doing the sql but show http 500 error

Comment: Please provide the actual PHP code you are using, actual SQL, and the error message(s). We can't help you without that information.

Comment: after looking for the error message, found that the problem is 'sql_mode=only_full_group_by', and i've solved it, thanks, @user3783243

Comment: Depending on how you solved it may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484068/what-are-the-benefits-of-only-full-group-by-mode.

Comment: Note that in general the GROUP BY should include all the non-aggregated columns in the SELECT. You query includes none of them.