# How to subtract based on condition in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, subtraction

I am very new to the mysql part, i have one table which contains multiple columns from that i want to check two columns if column1 is greater than column2 it should subtract **column1-column2**(amount-amount_refunded) and it store as a amount which will not effect any current functionality can you please help me to acheive this thing..

what i am trying is

```
SELECT
IF((amount > amount_refunded),amount-amount_refunded ,IFNULL(sum(amount), 0)) AS amount,
//remaining query
```

error i got

```
SQL Error [1055] [42000]: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'loach.charges.amount' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: What server are you using, is it local?

Comment: yes @IbrahimAbouKhalil, it is my local

Comment: Ok and are you using phpmyadmin?

Comment: No i am using `Dbeaver-ce` tool

Comment: Ok in your database you need to edit the variable 'sql_mode' and remove the value=only_full_group_by this might solve the issue.

Comment: Then same error will occur in prod server ryt..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242971/discussion-between-ibrahim-abou-khalil-and-usersuser).

Comment: @IbrahimAbouKhalil [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484068/what-are-the-benefits-of-only-full-group-by-mode) = You don't have to turn it off if you use `GROUP BY` properly!

Comment: @SimoneRossaini,before wrapping IF condition around the IFNULL it's not throwing any error

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Change `SUM (amount) ` to `amount` or group by the other columns of the select