# Query that sets a flag based on a condition for a group of left joined records

Tags: mysql, if-statement, left-join, ifnull

I have 2 tables, 'manufacturers' and 'products'. A manufacturer can have multiple products and a product has a 'qty', 'price' and 'cost' field.

**Manufacturers table**

| manufacturer_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |
| 2 | Meteor |
| 3 | XYZ |
| 4 | Airfix |

**Products table**

| product_id | manufacturer_id | price | cost | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 123.32 | 32.23 | 32 |
| 101 | 2 | 123.32 | 32.23 | 23 |
| 102 | 3 | 123.32 | 32.23 | 16 |
| 103 | 2 | 123.32 | 32.23 | 8 |
| 104 | 1 | 123.32 | 12.45 | 5 |
| 105 | 3 | 123.32 | 0.00 | 3 |
| 106 | 3 | 123.32 | 32.23 | 99 |
| 107 | 4 | 123.32 | 32.23 | 88 |

I've LEFT JOINed them together and can get SUMs on the 'price' and 'cost' fields based on multiplying by 'qty' but I'd like to get a 'cost_complete' flag set to false if ANY of the product.cost fields from a specific manufacturer are not set, thus allowing me to identify any manufacturer who has products that don't yet have a 'cost' set.

This is what I have so far, but I think that my 'cost_complete' flag gets overwritten for each product.

```
SELECT m.name, p.quantity, p.price, p.cost, 
SUM(p.quantity) AS total_quantity,
SUM(p.price*p.quantity) AS total_price,
SUM(p.cost*p.quantity) AS total_cost, IF(p.cost>0, 'true','false') AS cost_complete
FROM manufacturer m LEFT JOIN product p ON m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id GROUP BY m.manufacturer_id ORDER by m.name
```

Modified to explain what I am expecting:

| name | quantity | total_price | total_cost | cost_complete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 56 | £345.23 | £123.32 | true |
| Meteor | 12 | £1345.23 | £23.32 | true |
| XYZ | 123 | £345.23 | £65.12 | false |
| Airfix | 66 | £445.23 | £12.12 | true |

...where the cost_complete column is set to false when not all of the cost fields have a value greater than 0.

Comment: See #5 and #3 [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and update the qestion

Comment: edited to explain the table structure and what I would like the output to look like.

Comment: Your current query should be triggering a 1055 error. If not, you have [`ONLY_FULL GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) disabled, which you shouldn't. Please read [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) and [What are the benefits of only_full_group_by mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45484068/). Check this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_ZJeeTgS).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a conditional sum in case the p.cost is null (or is lower than 0 as you have in your code). Then you will have the number of products that don´t have a p.cost (if it is 0, all products have a cost)

```
SELECT m.name, p.quantity, p.price, p.cost, SUM(p.quantity) AS total_quantity, 
    SUM(p.price*p.quantity) AS total_price, SUM(p.cost*p.quantity) AS total_cost, 
    sum(case when p.cost>0 then 1 else 0 end) 
FROM manufacturer m 
LEFT JOIN product p ON m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id 
GROUP BY m.manufacturer_id 
ORDER by m.name
```

P.D. To answer your comment, you can do it this way:

```
SELECT m.name, p.quantity, p.price, p.cost, SUM(p.quantity) AS total_quantity, 
    SUM(p.price*p.quantity) AS total_price, SUM(p.cost*p.quantity) AS total_cost, 
    min(case when p.cost>0 then true else false end) 
FROM manufacturer m 
LEFT JOIN product p ON m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id 
GROUP BY m.manufacturer_id 
ORDER by m.name
```

Comment: Ive modified my original question to provide an example of what Id like the output to look like. The cost_complete column would be false if any of the product 'cost' fields were 0 or NULL.

Comment: I have modified my answer to fulfill your comment requeriments

Comment: This seems to return a '1' for the min(case when p.cost is null then false else true end)  part no matter whether each p.cost is 0, NULL or has a positive value

Comment: Why use a single-option CASE instead of IF?

Answer (score 0):

To query a list of manufacturers who have at least one product that has no cost set, this query should do.

```sql
SELECT
    m.name,
    SUM(p.quantity) AS total_quantity,
    SUM(p.price * p.quantity) AS total_price,
    SUM(p.cost * p.quantity) AS total_cost,
    MIN(IFNULL(p.cost, 0)) AS min_cost            #  see no. 2.4
FROM manufacturer m
    LEFT JOIN product p ON m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id
GROUP BY m.manufacturer_id
HAVING min_cost = 0                               #  see no. 3
ORDER BY m.name;
```

I'd like to imagine what this query does as follows:

1. For each manufacturer, get the list of products it manufactured.
2. For each list of products in step 1, go through each product and do the following:

   1. aggregate the quantity (as `total_quantity`),
   2. aggregate the price (as `total_price`),
   3. aggregate the total cost (as `total_cost`), and
   4. note the minimum cost among all products sifted through (as `min_cost`).
3. Only filter *in* manufacturers whose minimum product cost (`min_cost`) is zero.
4. Output manufacturer info, as well as the aggregated info gathered in step 2.
5. Sort step 4 by manufacturer name.

Notice how I removed `p.quantity`, `p.price`, and `p.cost` from the `SELECT` statement. This is because we used the `SELECT` statement to aggregate a summary about a list of products under a manufacturer; there's no picking a single product. In short, it won't make sense to include them anymore as there could be *more than one* product under the same manufacturer that have no `cost` set.

Also, as noted in the comments, I'm using the alias named `min_cost` in the `HAVING` clause. This is a MySQL extension to the standard SQL, making the syntax valid [by default](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50448), unless `sql_mode` is set to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.