# mysql query for one-to-many inner join

Tags: mysql

I have a table someone else built to track orders and they created a separate 'order_status' table but I just realized that they add a new 'status' record every time the status of an order in production changes, rather than updating a single record.

As a result, I need to search the table `order_item` WHERE status_code NOT IN (140,141) AND  ship_data = 0, but I also need the latest status from a table called `order_item_status` where the shared field is `order_id`

I don't know SQL well enough to know how to build such a query. I'm assumming it is some kind of subquery with a join and a limit 1 and/or group but I don't know how to bind the order_id between the two in such a query.

What I can show is two queries I can create:

listing orders not yet shipped or cancelled....

```
SELECT
    order_item.order_id, order_item.date_in, order_item.ship_date
FROM
    order_item
WHERE
    order_item.ship_date = 0 AND
    order_item_status.status_code NOT IN (140,141)
    ORDER BY order_item.date_in ASC;
```

Then assuming I have the order_id, I can find the most recent status for it with:

```
SELECT
    order_item_status.order_id, order_item_status.status_code, order_item_status.status_date
FROM
    order_item_status
WHERE
    order_item_status.order_id = :order_id
ORDER BY
    order_item_status.status_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But I have a feeling these can be done in a single query.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can find this general type of query answered many times under the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured something out. If anyone can offer suggestions to improve upon this, advice is appreciated.  (What I actually need is a count of items still marked as 'not shipped' and 'not cancelled'):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS in_production
FROM
    order_item
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT order_id, status_code, MAX(status_date) AS latest_status_date
        FROM order_item_status
        GROUP BY order_id
    ) latest_status ON order_item.order_id = latest_status.order_id
WHERE
    ship_date = 0 AND
    latest_status.status_code NOT IN (140,141)
    ORDER BY date_in ASC;
```

Comment: Your subquery is non-deterministic and does not return what you think it does. If you're not getting an error it is because you have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY disabled, which is bad! Please update your question with the DDL for the relevant tables, some sample data and desired output.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? It is not clear whether you want the count of orders with an item in production, or order_items in production. Please read this to get an understanding of the importance of ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY - [12.19.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). This [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65680378) has a good explanation of the problem. Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ptfs8xT-) highlighting the issue.

Comment: yeah, I figured that out eventually. I went with a programmatic solution to run the second query for the time being as i was running out of time to set aside for that project. I may revisit it at some point to do it all in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery and left join to achieve the result of two queries into one.

```
SELECT
 oi.order_id,
 oi.date_in,
 oi.ship_date,
 ois.status_code AS latest_status_code,
 ois.status_date AS latest_status_date
FROM
 order_item AS oi
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT
    order_id,
    MAX(status_date) AS latest_status_date
 FROM
    order_item_status
 WHERE
    status_code NOT IN (140, 141)
 GROUP BY
    order_id
 ) AS latest_status_subquery ON oi.order_id = latest_status_subquery.order_id
    LEFT JOIN order_item_status AS ois ON oi.order_id = ois.order_id AND 
    latest_status_subquery.latest_status_date = ois.status_date
    WHERE
      oi.ship_date = 0
    AND ois.status_code IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY
      oi.date_in ASC;
```

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look at this if I can set aside more time for this project. As mentioned in one of the comments on my tentative query, it wasn't producing what I thought so I switched to using a second call from a phpscript for now as I ran out of time to dedicate to this.

Comment: oh, I also ran into another issue outside this - turns out there were some older orders with multiple items where one item was cancelled and others were not. So I was getting a very high number as it was listing the 'unshipped' items by order, not by order_item specifically. (my external code solution addressed this also). Adding the item id to the group by may make a query like this work.