# Cumulative Sum using MySQL in Grafana v6.5.2

Tags: mysql, grafana, cumulative-sum

I am trying to use a Singlestat panel right now to show the cumulative uph at a specific hour.
The desired output is a just 4-digit numeric (ex: 7000).
The table is in hourly format, that shows that cumulative uph (units per hour).

This runs well in Navicat and shows the desired result.

Below is MySQL query. But it shows this error whenever I run it:

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @cumulative_uphB := 0;

**MySQL query:**

```sql
SET @cumulative_uphA := 0;
SET @cumulative_uphB := 0;

SELECT
*
-- cumulative_uph
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN time = '06' THEN '1'
            WHEN time = '07' THEN '2'
            WHEN time = '08' THEN '3'
            WHEN time = '09' THEN '4'
            WHEN time = '10' THEN '5'
            WHEN time = '11' THEN '6'
            WHEN time = '12' THEN '7'
            WHEN time = '13' THEN '8'
            WHEN time = '14' THEN '9'
            WHEN time = '15' THEN '10'
            WHEN time = '16' THEN '11'
            WHEN time = '17' THEN '12'
            WHEN time = '18' THEN '13'
            WHEN time = '19' THEN '14'
            WHEN time = '20' THEN '15'
            WHEN time = '21' THEN '16'
            WHEN time = '22' THEN '17'
            WHEN time = '23' THEN '18'
            WHEN time = '00' THEN '19'
            WHEN time = '01' THEN '20'
            WHEN time = '02' THEN '21'
            WHEN time = '03' THEN '22'
            WHEN time = '04' THEN '23'
            WHEN time = '05' THEN '24'
        END AS sequence,
        time,
        uph,
        CASE
            WHEN time BETWEEN '06' AND '17' THEN (@cumulative_uphA := @cumulative_uphA + uph)
            WHEN time BETWEEN '18' AND '23' THEN (@cumulative_uphB := @cumulative_uphB + uph)
            WHEN time BETWEEN '00' AND '05' THEN (@cumulative_uphB := @cumulative_uphB + uph)
        END AS cumulative_uph,
        CASE
            WHEN time BETWEEN '06' AND '17' THEN '1'
            WHEN time BETWEEN '18' AND '23' THEN '2'
            WHEN time BETWEEN '00' AND '05' THEN '2'
        END AS shift
    FROM (
        SELECT
            time,
            CASE
                WHEN time BETWEEN '06' AND '17' THEN
                    CASE
                        WHEN time = '06' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '07' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '08' THEN uph * 0.5
                        WHEN time = '09' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '10' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '11' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '12' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '13' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '14' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '15' THEN uph * 0.5
                        WHEN time = '16' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '17' THEN uph * 0.75
                    END
                WHEN time BETWEEN '18' AND '23' THEN
                    CASE
                        WHEN time = '18' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '19' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '20' THEN uph * 0.5
                        WHEN time = '21' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '22' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '23' THEN uph * 1
                    END
                WHEN time BETWEEN '00' AND '05' THEN
                    CASE
                        WHEN time = '00' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '01' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '02' THEN uph * 0.5
                        WHEN time = '03' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '04' THEN uph * 1
                        WHEN time = '05' THEN uph * 0.75
                    END
            END AS uph
        FROM (
            SELECT
                hours.hour AS time,
                IFNULL(tb_monthly.incremental_uph, 700) AS uph
            FROM (
                SELECT '06' AS hour
                UNION SELECT '07' UNION SELECT '08' UNION SELECT '09' UNION SELECT '10' UNION SELECT '11' UNION SELECT '12'
                UNION SELECT '13' UNION SELECT '14' UNION SELECT '15' UNION SELECT '16' UNION SELECT '17'
                UNION SELECT '18' UNION SELECT '19' UNION SELECT '20' UNION SELECT '21' UNION SELECT '22' UNION SELECT '23'
                UNION SELECT '00' UNION SELECT '01' UNION SELECT '02' UNION SELECT '03' UNION SELECT '04' UNION SELECT '05'
            ) AS hours
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H') AS hour,
                    uph AS incremental_uph
                FROM tb_monthly
                WHERE
                    (
                        (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H') BETWEEN '06' AND '17')
                        OR
                        (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H') BETWEEN '18' AND '23')
                        OR
                        (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H') BETWEEN '00' AND '05')
                    )
                    AND customer = 'TSB'
                    AND xmodel = 'FJ1XC'
                    AND line = '3'
                    AND assembly = 'MOTOR'
                GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H')
            ) AS tb_monthly ON hours.hour = tb_monthly.hour
            ORDER BY hours.hour
        ) a
    ) b
    ORDER BY CAST(sequence AS SIGNED)
) c
WHERE time = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H');
```

**Result:**

| sequence | time | uph | cumulative_uph | shift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 16 | 700 | 7000 | 1 |

Comment: Set initial variables values in additional SELECT subquery, not in separate SET statements. I.e. add `SELECT .. FROM .. CROSS JOIN (SELECT @variable1:=value1,  @variable2:=value2) AS init_variables WHERE ..`. Also you may replace your long `CASE WHEN time = '06' THEN '1' WHEN ...` with `FIND_IN_SET(time, '06,07,...')`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: hi @Akina thank you for the reminder, i apologize for this one

Comment: hi @Akina thank you for the advice! i'll try this one. then i'll post an update

Comment: hi @Akina , I have tried your advice using Cross Join;  for your suggestion of FIND_IN_SET function, i just used "IN" instead on my WHERE clause for every CASE WHEN.. this worked well ! I am now able to calculate the cumulative UPH value based on the current hour :) i hope your comment was written as an Answer so i could tag it as "Helpful in finding Solution"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your current query.

Let's start with the innermost query:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H') AS hour,
    uph AS incremental_uph
FROM tb_monthly
WHERE
    (
        (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H') BETWEEN '06' AND '17')
        OR
        (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H') BETWEEN '18' AND '23')
        OR
        (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H') BETWEEN '00' AND '05')
    )
    AND customer = 'TSB'
    AND xmodel = 'FJ1XC'
    AND line = '3'
    AND assembly = 'MOTOR'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H')
```

You should be getting an error along the lines of:

> Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'tb_monthly.uph' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

as the innermost query is [non-deterministic](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html#:%7E:text=the%20values%20chosen%20are%20nondeterministic). If it is not raising an error, you must have [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) disabled, which is not good (see [What are the benefits of only_full_group_by mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45484068/)).

Consider the following three rows (guessing as you haven't provided sample data):

| time | uph | customer | xmodel | line | assembly |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 600 | TSB | FJ1XC | 3 | MOTOR |
| 14 | 700 | TSB | FJ1XC | 3 | MOTOR |
| 15 | 800 | TSB | FJ1XC | 3 | MOTOR |

Given the current time `15:57:17` (my locale at time of writing) your innermost SELECT equates to (before GROUP BY):

| hour | incremental_uph |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | 600 |
| 15 | 700 |
| 15 | 800 |

Now your `GROUP BY` wants to "squash" this to one row. Which value of `uph` should it return? Also, as the expression in your `GROUP BY` has a constant value, it is the same as writing `GROUP BY 'donkey'`.

The three `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H')` criteria in the `WHERE` clause serve no purpose, as one of them will always be true.

The first of your rather long CASE operations:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN time = '06' THEN '1'
    WHEN time = '07' THEN '2'
    ...
    WHEN time = '05' THEN '24'
END AS sequence,
```

which you then CAST to a SIGNED INT - `ORDER BY CAST(sequence AS SIGNED)`, can be simplified to:

```sql
IF (time > '05', time - 5, time + 24 - 5) AS sequence,
```

The second big CASE operation with the nested CASE operations, can be simplified to:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN time IN ('02', '08', '15', '20') THEN uph * 0.5
    WHEN time IN ('05', '17') THEN uph * 0.75
    ELSE uph
END AS uph
```

There is a possible issue with the cumulative `SUM` depending on your intended order of cumulation. Should it be `hours.hour` (current), or `sequence`?

Finally, as Akina has already pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77451744/cumulative-sum-using-mysql-in-grafana-v6-5-2#comment136543297_77451744), you should initialise your user variables within your query, instead of relying on being able to execute multiple queries.

Here's modified query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        IF (time > '05', time - 5, time + 24 - 5) AS sequence,
        time,
        uph,
        CASE
            WHEN time BETWEEN '06' AND '17' THEN (@cumulative_uphA := @cumulative_uphA + uph)
            WHEN time BETWEEN '18' AND '23' THEN (@cumulative_uphB := @cumulative_uphB + uph)
            WHEN time BETWEEN '00' AND '05' THEN (@cumulative_uphB := @cumulative_uphB + uph)
        END AS cumulative_uph,
        CASE
            WHEN time BETWEEN '06' AND '17' THEN '1'
            WHEN time BETWEEN '18' AND '23' THEN '2'
            WHEN time BETWEEN '00' AND '05' THEN '2'
        END AS shift
    FROM (
        SELECT
            time,
            CASE
                WHEN time IN ('02', '08', '15', '20') THEN uph * 0.5
                WHEN time IN ('05', '17') THEN uph * 0.75
                ELSE uph
            END AS uph
        FROM (
            SELECT
                hours.hour AS time,
                IFNULL(tb_monthly.incremental_uph, 700) AS uph
            FROM (
                SELECT '06' AS hour
                UNION SELECT '07' UNION SELECT '08' UNION SELECT '09' UNION SELECT '10' UNION SELECT '11' UNION SELECT '12'
                UNION SELECT '13' UNION SELECT '14' UNION SELECT '15' UNION SELECT '16' UNION SELECT '17'
                UNION SELECT '18' UNION SELECT '19' UNION SELECT '20' UNION SELECT '21' UNION SELECT '22' UNION SELECT '23'
                UNION SELECT '00' UNION SELECT '01' UNION SELECT '02' UNION SELECT '03' UNION SELECT '04' UNION SELECT '05'
            ) AS hours
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H') AS hour,
                    ANY_VALUE(uph) AS incremental_uph
                FROM tb_monthly
                -- we need to initialise your variables somewhere
                JOIN (SELECT @cumulative_uphA := 0, @cumulative_uphB := 0) AS init
                WHERE customer = 'TSB'
                  AND xmodel = 'FJ1XC'
                  AND line = '3'
                  AND assembly = 'MOTOR'
                GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H')
            ) AS tb_monthly ON hours.hour = tb_monthly.hour
            ORDER BY hours.hour
        ) a
    ) b
    ORDER BY CAST(sequence AS SIGNED)
) c
WHERE time = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H');
```

Note: [`ANY_VALUE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) added to `uph` in innermost query (to stop 1055 error), and variable initialisation added.

And here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ruICffRM).

Comment: hi @user1191247 thank you for the advice! i'll try this one. then i'll post an update

Comment: hi @user1191247, to clarify also about the result for the innermost query, it returns only one incremental value (example result : 700) for the current hour. thank you still for your advice and for evaluating my query!

Comment: My point about the innermost query being [non-deterministic](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html#:%7E:text=the%20values%20chosen%20are%20nondeterministic) is that, unless the `WHERE` clause is reducing the result set to a single possible `uph` value, the value of `uph` returned could be any value. It is not possible to provide a more useful answer without having sample data and desired output. If you update your question I, or someone else, will be able to provide a more succinct answer.