# What is a client in MySQL and does changing setting in a client change the setting for other databases?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I ran into an error that caused me to change the setting for MySQL through MySQL Workbench.
The command was

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

I used it in my local database.

So, does the change only apply to MySQL Workbench and my Local database?

Or, Do I need to change the mode for my other databases?

I have not tried to run it in AWS lambda. I am not sure if it needs to be applied there.

Comment: Running `SET GLOBAL var_name` sets the variable at the server (instance) level but it will not persist after restart. If you run `SET SESSION var_name` or leave out the scope completely it is set for the current session only. You can read more here - [System Variable Assignment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html#set-variable-system-variables). More importantly, instead of disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, you should fix the query that required you to disable it. Read more here - [What are the benefits of only_full_group_by mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45484068/).